# Error Handling in CI

Tags: codeigniter, logging

I read [Error Handling](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) but if I use `log_message('debug', 'Hi I m in Cart Controller');` or `log_message('info', 'Hi I m in Cart Controller');` it does not log any message but work only for `log_message('error', 'Hi I m in Cart Controller');`

Any idea what my mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the log threshold in `app/config/config.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to 
| determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```